# Make 2 Create Line From in 1 Window iDempiere

Tags: java, oop, idempiere

I need customization to make 2 different Create Line From in 1 Window. The reason I need to make this because the security for our client because the behavior to take data is different from the original.

I have already read some suggestion in this topic [Adempiere - How to design/call 2 CreateLinesFrom button in Same window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045589/adempiere-how-to-design-call-2-createlinesfrom-button-in-same-window)

But still need the details, how I can do it properly?

Thanks

Comment: you mean "how do I trigger two statements on button click?"

Comment: no i mean new button and new statement. sorry if my question not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved

This link will help https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/idempiere/MMGlpMunsLM

Summary from the link :

1. Make Column CreateFromOther
2. Generate model
3. Make new Class ICreateFromOtherFactory copy from ICreateFromFactory and just change `create` become `createOther`
4. Make new Class WCreateFromOtherFactory copy from WCreateFromFactory and change all code `ICreateFromFactory` become `ICreateFromOtherFactory` and `create` become `createOther`
5. Deploy fragment for org.adempiere.ui.zk and change the code in AbstratctADWindowContent actionButton0
6. Make plugin CreateFromOther extends CreateFrom and WCreateFromOther extends CreateFromOther
7. Make Factory for this plugin reference to ICreateFromOtherFactory
8. Make Component Definition and include the services ICreateFromOtherFactory

Thanks